# Switch off keyboard backlight on new MacBooks

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

Older MacBooks had a dedicated key to switch off the keyboard backlight (like the mute key). It was <kbd>F8</kbd> if I'm not mistaken.

Is it possible to replicate its functionality (e.g.: keyboard shortcut) on the new models?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is probably to just hold down the dimmer key. Should turn it off less than a second. However it sounds like you want a single press button to turn it off.

It's a bit convoluted, but it should work:
Using Automator, make an application out of the Applescript from [this MacRumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=6724429&postcount=6). To do this, open Automator, choose *Application* from the options, search for the *Run AppleScript* action and add it to the workflow, paste in the script and save. You should end up with something like this:
[image: Automator script]That should give you an application that will disable the backlight.

[QuickSilver](http://qsapp.com/) is free, and you can set a "trigger" to launch the app and bind it to any key you want. If you want to use a function key, try [FunctionFlip](http://kevingessner.com/software/functionflip/). It lets you choose which function keys on your MacBook you want to work as actual F-keys and which you want controlling the hardware functions. You can rebind whatever F-key you like and still use the rest for hardware functions if you like.

It's worth noting that the Applescript seems to be a disable-only script. There are directions on the accompanying post to make an enable script. With a bit of modification you could probably make it a toggle script, maybe someone else could chime in with that?

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn it off as follows:

- Apple menu > System Preferences...
- Keyboard > Toggle "Automatically illuminate keyboard in low light"

Note: If you disable the option, you can dim keyboard light with <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd>.

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: Sorry, I was misled by your title. Guess the answer is helpful if you like to dim by function keys. I'm not aware of an ON/OFF functionality on new MacBooks.